# tableToGrid on a dynamically generated table

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using the jqgrid version 3.8 and using the tableToGrid plugin to convert my dynamically generated html table to a jqgrid. My code looks something like this

```
tableToGrid("#content", {
             rowNum: 10,
             rowList: [10, 20, 30]
         });
```

where content is the table ID and I am doing this on click of a button, generating the html on the server side and slapping the html onto a div.

The problem I have here is, I still dont see any change in the html table meaning I dont get the sort option, search etc.

I have recently started using jqgrid so any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any errors when you execute `tableToGrid`? If not I think you will need to post more code or a small example of the problem via jsfiddle, so we can narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the options parameter you need to state that the grid is sortable by default it is false.

```
tableToGrid("#content", {
             rowNum: 10,
             rowList: [10, 20, 30],
             sortable: true
         });
```

Here are the grid [options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) that are available.

```
tableToGrid(selector, options)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesnt seem to have any effect. Does it matter if the html table is generated dynamically on the server side depending on the user selection ?

Comment: As long as the markup for the table exists before tableToGrid is called I would think not.